# How should I center the fixed position element occupied by translateX？

Tags: html, css, center, fixed

I want an HTML element centered horizontally,
example:

```css
.u-message {
    position fixed
    left 50%
    //transform: translateX(-50%); //but css animate occupy translateX, so i cant's use transform attribute,
    //margin-left: xxxpx;  //and I dont't sure how long of the HTML element width,so I cant's use it too.
}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Please show us the animation (both the keyframes and the animation property setting) since it's central to this problem.

Comment: I use a lib of "animate.css" ，so maybe I will toggle many different animate name in the HTML element.

Comment: so i think i can't deduce what should I write transfrom attribute from keyframes

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex box

```
.u-message {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: thank your, I guess I can wrap the HTML element，and add style above in father HTML emelent。after I was success !